# A problem in a metric space involving limits

Tags: metric-spaces, self-learning

Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space, $A,B\subseteq E$ and $a\in A$. If $A$ is compact and $B$ closed and I find a sequence $b_n$ in $B$ so that $d(a,b_n)\rightarrow 0 $, is there any way to conclude that $a \in B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$d(a,b_n) \to 0$ means $b_n \to a$. Since $B$ is closed $a \in B$.

Comment: But $b_n \rightarrow a$ implies $a$ is a limit point of $B$? Why?

Comment: If $b_n=a$ for some $n$ then it is obvious that $a=b_n \in B$. Otherwise, $a$ is a limit point.